# Как можно сократить js код?

Tags: javascript

Подскажите пожалуйста как можно сократить код, что бы при нажатии на кнопку она становилась активной, а другие кнопки нет

```js
let trueBtn = document.querySelector('.btn__true');
let falseBtn = document.querySelector('.btn__false');
let allBtn = document.querySelector('.btn__all');

let commentsTrue = document.querySelector('.comments__true');
let commentsFalse = document.querySelector('.comments__false');

allBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    commentsTrue.classList.remove('hidden');
    commentsFalse.classList.remove('hidden');

    allBtn.classList.add('active');
    trueBtn.classList.remove('active');
    falseBtn.classList.remove('active');
})

trueBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    commentsFalse.classList.add('hidden');
    commentsTrue.classList.remove('hidden');
    
    trueBtn.classList.add('active');
    allBtn.classList.remove('active');
    falseBtn.classList.remove('active');
})

falseBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    commentsTrue.classList.add('hidden');
    commentsFalse.classList.remove('hidden');

    falseBtn.classList.add('active');
    allBtn.classList.remove('active');
    trueBtn.classList.remove('active');
})
```

Comment: А разметку кто писать будет?

Answer (score 0):

Что-то такое получилось. Могут быть опечатки, не проверял. Повторяющейся логики нет:

```js
let trueBtn = document.querySelector('.btn__true');
let falseBtn = document.querySelector('.btn__false');
let allBtn = document.querySelector('.btn__all');

let commentsTrue = document.querySelector('.comments__true');
let commentsFalse = document.querySelector('.comments__false');

const setClass = (target, class_, set) => {
    if (set) {
        target.classList.add(class_);
    } else {
        target.classList.remove(class_);
    }
};

const listener = source => {
    setClass(commentsTrue, 'hidden', source === falseBtn);
    setClass(commentsFalse, 'hidden', source === trueBtn);
    for (const target of [allBtn, trueBtn, falseBtn]) {
        setClass(target, 'active', source === target);
    }
};

for (const source of [allBtn, trueBtn, falseBtn]) {
    source.addEventListener('click', () => listener(source));
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Самый простой вариант - сгруппировать элементы в массив и сравнивать элемент с обработчиком события с другими элементами в массиве.
Вот:

```
const btns = [trueBtn, falseBtn, allBtn];

btns.forEach(e => e.onclick = function () {
  btns.forEach(el => el === this ? el.classList.add("active") : el.classList.remove("active"))
});
```

Comment: А минус за что?